# How do I solve "Roller Weblogger has not been bootstrapped yet"?

Tags: tomcat, apache-roller

I'm getting the following error when I try to access Roller:

[image]

I'm running it on Tomcat on Windows 7. I've just put the roller.war file in the webapps folder, Tomcat is properly configured, but Roller does not work. How do I solved it? Why this error happens?

Comment: Could you paste relevant parts of log files of Roller and Tomcat here? Roller log is placed on the path that you have specified in roller-custom.properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two situations that make this error:
The first check the connection to the Database (do you use correct driver or not).
The second is to check that `javax.mail.jar` exists in the `lib` folder of tomcat.

Hope this help you resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error is often presented if the database is not started or not accessible. You might find some messages like "RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool RollerPool" in your Tomcat's log files.